# How do I make a comment when I am told I need 50 reputation?

Tags: support, comments

A post instructs me to post the results of a terminal command, but when I try to add a comment I'm stopped by a 50 reputation requirement. Not a very welcome introduction.

Comment: Edit your question to include the results of the command.

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Which question are you referring to here?

Comment: You have no question or answer on AskDifferent - what are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Please see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment to understand how the comment system works. You can always comment on your own posts though, so if you are asked to clarify something on your own question or answer you can always do so.

To improve existing questions or answers it is also possible to edit those posts directly (there is an "edit" link beneath every post for this).